# RS232 issue with 0x0A and 0x0D while sending a message

Tags: perl, serial-port

I'm running a code that composes a message and send it over RS232 bus to a device.

I'm having issues when the message has 0A (new line) or 0D (carriage return) chars (or both) on the message.

The reading side is telling me that it doesn't understand the message (by sending me a NAK response). I've deduced that the issue is with those two chars.

ie:

```
022620255846060A00003003
022620255946060D00003703
```

Any thoughts of how may I send the same information without having to change the 0A or 0D?

The code that I'm using for sending the message is this:

```
my $stt = pack 'H*',$msg;
$ob_w->write($stt);
```

being $msg equal to one of the above codes and $ob_w is the port itself.

Thanks

Comment: In which order did you try both of them? To my understanding, you are required to use CR LF (0D 0A) at the end of lines in serial communication.

Comment: This is nothing to to with RS232: it is just a byte sequence. What protocol is being used? And what software is reading from the interface? If you are using a Perl program at line level then you must be careful to avoid any semantic conversions. That essentially means using `open ':<:raw`, $source`.

Comment: What operating system are you working with?

Comment: @Silvar The communication is delimited by STX and ETX. 0D and 0A are the result of some calculations made for generating those strings showed in the example.

Comment: @Borodin I'm using Device::SerialPort for handle all the communication. The software that will receive the message is a SW from a lift manufacturer. All we got is the protocol definition, we don't have access to the receiving software. I'm not reading from any file, I'm getting data from a database and doing some maths to generate the message, then, I send it. The OS is raspbian under a Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, this was an issue related with serial port configuration.

By changing from

```
$ob_w->stty_icrnl (1);
$ob_w->stty_ocrnl (1);
$ob_w->stty_onlcr (1);
$ob_w->stty_opost (1);
```

to:

```
$ob_w->stty_icrnl (0);
$ob_w->stty_ocrnl (0);
$ob_w->stty_onlcr (0);
$ob_w->stty_opost (0);
```

will fix the message. Some of the orders from above was changing 0x0A and 0x0D to 0x0A0D, so in this particular case, the receiving machine calculates the checksum and discard the message because the checksum received and generated was not the same.

Answer (score 0):

When outputting binary data with perl, it seems that it is necessary to set it to binmode and then output it by print. Please refer to the following article.

[How to work with binary data in a perl script](https://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-work-with-binary-data-in-a-perl-script)

---

#### In Addition:

[Input and Output in Binary Mode 1](http://www.herongyang.com/Perl/binary.html)
[Input and Output in Binary Mode 2](http://www.herongyang.com/Perl/binary_2.html)
[How to read and write the serial port using perl](http://www.fibrevillage.com/scripting/366-how-to-read-and-write-the-serial-port-using-perl)
[Accessing Serial port on windows and Linux](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=688080)
[perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html)
[Handling Binary Files in Perl](http://www.devx.com/DevX/Tip/17116)

Comment: The problem is not printing it. The problem is sending the data. I don't mind about the actual representation of the data, just need to know how to send the data properly

Comment: The name of the function is print, but it does not mean printing to paper or screen. I can not find exactly good articles, but I added some helpful articles.

Comment: Just finished reading everything and I found it a really interesting reading most of all. What I wonder is that using binmode $stt before packing and sending through serial port will make any changes to the output in the other side. I'm burning a raspbian image to run the code in a RPI (same distro that is using under production) and will check it out.

Comment: Just added an answer to clarify how to fix this. Thanks for your help and for those links