# Send to serial x0A

Tags: serial-port

I managed my COM device (Serial connect) under the Linux console.
For example, if I had run this command:

```
echo -ne '\x55\x90\x17\x01\x00' > /dev/ttyACM0
my device receive command and execute, but if i Run this command:
echo -ne '\x55\x90\x0A\x01\x00' > /dev/ttyACM0
```

device do not execute this command.
I know, the problem with `x0A`, because of this code associated with the command.
My question, how to send `xOA` string to the device.

Comment: May I suggest you edit your question a little to make it easier to read, say, by using the code formatting?

Answer (score 0):

This article is a related Q&A of a similar phenomenon when communicating with perl.
[RS232 issue with 0x0A and 0x0D while sending a message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52076840/9014308)

It seems to be ok if you disable the function to convert the serial port character code by the stty command etc.
[Unix man pages: stty (1)](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/stty.1.html)

Comment: yes, I use stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200 raw -echo, manual is too complicated, what exactly parameter I must add to stty?

Comment: Firstly, if there is a setting on the device side try it the same way (raw), then, try disabling the four items in that article.  -icrnl, -ocrnl, -onlcr, -opost.

Comment: stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200 raw -echo -icrnl -ocrnl -onlcr -opost, do not help.the device doesn't have any problem, when I send this command under Windows with RealTerm 0xA, device accepted command like intended, 0xA is registry address in the device.

Comment: Another thing to think about is try `echo -e` instead of `echo -ne`.

Comment: My question is still open, how to send 0xA to a device like a data? currently, stty interpreted and sending like a "new line" command.

Comment: Guys, I am new at this forum, maybe this is the wrong place for this question?

Comment: There may not be new advice for people watching the tag "serial-port". How about re-asking with a tag such as a large range of linux/unix, or the distribution you are using(such as ubuntu), or the hardware you are using(such as raspberry-pi)?

Answer (score 0):

Some tty devices keep LF to CRLF conversion output on. You can disable it using:

`stty -onlcr -F /dev/ttyACM0`

or, for strict POSIX stay

`stty -onlcr < -F /dev/ttyACM0`

and then try

`echo -ne '\x55\x90\x0A\x01\x00' > /dev/ttyACM0`